# How to change the color of polygon with Leaflet in real time?

Tags: polygon, leaflet, color, real-time

I am trying to display a polygon from an external GeoJSON file, the data loads but does not update the polygon in real time with "nivel".

The polygon is added but color is not updated after interval when level changes.

Heres is my code:

```
    const getShapesLayerGroupRealTime = (idCliente) => {
    const shapesLayerGroup = new L.LayerGroup();
    const realtimeReference = L.realtime(
        {
            url: ENDPOINT_DATA_GEOSERVICIOS,
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                solicitud: 'shpCliente',
                idCliente: idCliente,
            }),
        },
        {
            container: shapesLayerGroup,
            interval: REALTIME_INTERVAL_SECONDS * 1000,
            pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) => (
                L.polygon(latlng,{
                    color: '#51F03B'
                })
            ),
            removeMissing: true,
            updateFeature: (feature, oldLayer, newLayer) => newLayer,
        }
    );
    return [shapesLayerGroup, realtimeReference];
 }
```

my GeoJSON:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -76.256104,
                            4.696879
                        ],
                        [
                            -76.256104,
                            5.550381
                        ],
                        [
                            -75.289307,
                            5.550381
                        ],
                        [
                            -75.289307,
                            4.696879
                        ],
                        [
                            -76.256104,
                            4.696879
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": 2,
                "propiedades": "{\"descripcion\":\"s\"}",
                "nivel": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -76.624146,
                            5.823687
                        ],
                        [
                            -75.322266,
                            6.713709
                        ],
                        [
                            -76.195679,
                            5.741708
                        ],
                        [
                            -76.624146,
                            5.823687
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": 3,
                "propiedades": "{\"descripcion\":\"s\"}",
                "nivel": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -75.635376,
                    5.566783
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": 1,
                "propiedades": "{\"descripcion\":\"Prueba 1\"}",
                "nivel": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

I want to change this blue color

Comment: You're using `pointToLayer` for polygons, and the colour doesn't seem to depend on the `nivel` property of the features. Do check those issues first.

Comment: Y try to change and not work , i use '#51F03B' to change but don't work

Comment: Read https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/ first.

Comment: Yes, it works but I don't know if it updates automatically, Thanks for this moment, I will try in two days and confirm it is work, for this moment I answer the result

Answer (score 1):

I try with this, but i don't know if update

```
 const getShapesLayerGroupRealTime = (idCliente) => {
const shapesLayerGroup = new L.LayerGroup();
const realtimeReference = L.realtime(
    {
        url: ENDPOINT_DATA_GEOSERVICIOS,
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            solicitud: 'shpCliente',
            idCliente: idCliente,
        }),
    },
    {
        container: shapesLayerGroup,
        
        pointToLayer:(feature, latlng) =>(
            L.circle((latlng),{
                color: getShapeColor(feature)
            })
        ),
        style: (feature)=>(
            {color: getShapeColor(feature)}
        ),
        removeMissing: true,
        updateFeature: (feature, oldLayer, newLayer) => newLayer,
        
    }
);
return [shapesLayerGroup, realtimeReference];
```

}

and the color

```
const getShapeColor = (feature) => {     
    
    if (feature.properties.nivel === 1) {
        return color_shape_one
    }else if (feature.properties.nivel === 0) {
        return color_shape_two
    }else{
        return '#000000'
    }
};
```

[image]